# Error occurs in Ninja while building CMake

Tags: android, cmake, android-ndk, ninja

An error occurs while I am building CMake.

build.gradle  file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'   android {
compileSdkVersion 29
buildToolsVersion "29.0.3"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.ffmpeg"
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 29
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"

    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            cppFlags "-frtti -fexceptions"
            abiFilters 'arm64-v8a'
        }
    }
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
externalNativeBuild {
    cmake {
        path file('CMakeLists.txt')
    }
}}dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'}
```

[image]

ERROR
[image]

MY project

[image]

Project Structure

[image]

How can I solve this error?

```
Build command failed.

Error while executing process D:\install\sdk\cmake\3.10.2.4988404\bin\ninja.exe with arguments {-C D:\Android projects\ffmpeg\app\.cxx\cmake\debug\arm64-v8a native-lib}

ninja: Entering directory `D:\Android projects\ffmpeg\app\.cxx\cmake\debug\arm64-v8a'

ninja: error: FindFirstFileExA(/d:/install/sdk/ndk/21.0.6113669/arm64-v8a): The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
```

Comment: Something appears to wrong with your configuration, as the path ninja is trying to use is incorrect. Did you try cleaning the CMake cache, and doing a Re-run CMake?

Comment: Your project path contains a space. Have you tried using a path that doesn't have any spaces?

Comment: Michael  my project path does not contains any spaces.

Comment: squareskittles How can I cleaning the CMake cache.

Comment: _"my project path does not contains any spaces."_  `D:\Android projects\ffmpeg` <-- There's a space between 'Android' and 'projects'.

Comment: I removed the space but it  not work.

Comment: I have a same error , have you got solution?

Comment: Just go to android studio's home page , then , create a new project there is an option for creating an android app with native libs choose that option.  It will work .

Answer (score 1):

Delete this code from build.gradle file and build again. It worked for me.

```
externalNativeBuild {
    cmake {
        path file('CMakeLists.txt')
    }
}
```